# Unable to find ajax json data on the server side

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to send some data from jquery on the client side to a codeigniter controller. I have :

```
var data = {
    "value" : value,
    "message" : message
};

console.log(postData);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "my_controller/my_function",
    data: data, 
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(){

    }
});
```

This appears to be working properly as I can see the correct post parameters in chrome dev tools. In my codeigniter controller I have tried:

```
echo 'post' . $_POST['value'].' '.$_POST['message'];

$postData=$this->input->post('value');

var_dump($postData); exit;
```

I'm getting:

```
Message: Undefined index: value
Message: Undefined index: message

boolean(false)
```

the `$_POST` array is empty.

How can I fix this? Thank you for your help

Comment: Try to remove the dataType line as jQuery detects the dataType itself very good.

Comment: Are you actually setting the value and message variables? It doesn't show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code I got this that works well:

js:

```
var data = {
    value : '_value_',
    message : '_message_'
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php.php",
    data: data, 
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(postData){
        console.log(postData);
    }
});
```

and in the php file php.php:

```
<?php

echo json_encode($_POST);

?>
```

And as a result I got this in the browser's console:

Object {value: "*value*", message: "*message*"}

Answer (score 0):

You can simply follow the code

```
var data = {
    value : value,
    message : message
};    

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>my_controller/my_function',
    data: data, 
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(responseFromServer){
        console.log(responseFromServer);
    }
});
```

In controller action method you can find those value just use this code

```
$postData= $this->input->post('value');
$message= $this->input->post('message');
```

Before return any thing just use these code

```
 header('Content-Type: application/json', true);
 echo json_encode($postData);
```

Now you find an array of Object in client side.